# Store values in variables from jquery price range slider

Tags: jquery

I have followed a youtube tutorial on price range slider with jquery. I have succeeded in that price slider but now I am stuck with storing the lower and upper price value in a variable so that I can then use it sql query to show results based upon that price. My function is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#slider").slider({
    max: 50,
    range: true,
    values: [15, 30],
    change: function(event, ui) {
      getDetails(ui.values[0], ui.values[1]);
    }
  });
  var current = $("#slider").slider("option", "values");
  getDetails(current[0], current[1]);
});

function getDetails(minimum, maximum) {
  $("#range").text("$" + minimum + " - $" + maximum);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.6.2/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <label for="myRange">Price Range <span id="range"></span> </label><br>
  <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```

Please help me how can I store minimum and maximum values into variable and then store that variables in my sql query. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I made you a snippet.

Comment: Sir can you please tell me how can I get min and max values that is set by user and store to the variables?

Comment: var slider = new Slider("#slider");
slider.on("slide", function(sliderValue)
{
var leftSliderValue = sliderValue[0];
var rightSliderValue = sliderValue[1];
});

Comment: Thanks and how can I use this javascript variable to my php code as SQL query is in php code and I have to use this variables in my that query